# Is there an equivalent Matlab dot function in numpy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Is there an equivalent Matlab `dot` function in numpy?

The `dot` function in Matlab:
For multidimensional arrays A and B, dot returns the scalar product along the first non-singleton dimension of A and B. A and B must have the same size.

In numpy the following is similar but not equivalent:

```
dot (A.conj().T, B)
```

Comment: What type are your A and B? Numpy arrays or numpy matrices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MATLAB, `dot(A,B)` of two matrices `A` and `B` of same size is simply:

```
sum(conj(A).*B)
```

Equivalent Python/Numpy:

```
np.sum(A.conj()*B, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab example1:

`A = [1,2,3;4,5,6]
B = [7,8,9;10,11,12]
dot(A,B)`

Result:
    47    71    99

Matlab example2:

`sum(A.*B)`

Result:
47    71    99

Numpy version of Matlab example2:

`A = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
B = np.matrix([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
np.multiply(A,B).sum(axis=0)`

Result:
matrix([[47, 71, 99]])

Answer (score -1):

Check these cheatsheets.

- Numpy's [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220905003700/https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)
- http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html

> Numpy contains both an array class and a matrix class. The array class is intended to be a general-purpose n-dimensional array for many kinds of numerical computing, while matrix is intended to facilitate linear algebra computations specifically. In practice there are only a handful of key differences between the two.
>
> Operator `*`, dot(), and multiply():
> For array, `*` means element-wise multiplication, and the dot() function is used for matrix multiplication.
> For matrix, `*` means matrix multiplication, and the multiply() function is used for element-wise multiplication.